# Do the spacers separating CPU cooler from mainboard belong to the cooler or the mainboard?

Tags: motherboard, cpu-cooler, screws

I want to sell the parts of an old computer on eBay, but am unsure where the four spacing screws separating mainboard and cooler belong to. Do these screws generally come with the mainboard or with the cooler? The mainboard is an [AsRock P43DE](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/P43DE/index.asp).

[image]

Comment: "Do these screws generally come with the mainboard or with the cooler?" - Edit your question to indicate which cooler you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These come from a cooler. Motherboards have only mounting holes in location specific for the CPU platform.

Answer (score 2):

> Do these screws generally come with the mainboard or with the cooler? The mainboard is an AsRock P43DE.

Based on the package contents for the AsRock P43DE it wasn't included with your motherboard.  Since I regonize the spacers in question, I know they came with the unidentified cooler, not the motherboard.

> 1.1 Package Contents:
>
> - ASRock P43DE Motherboard
> - ASRock P43DE Quick Installation Guide
> - ASRock P43DE Support CD
> - 1 80-conductor Ultra ATA 66/100/133 IDE Ribbon Cable
> - 2 Serial ATA (SATA) Data Cables (Optional)
> - 1 Serial ATA (SATA) HDD Power Cable (Optional)
> - 1 I/O Panel Shield

Souce: [AsRock P43DE Manual](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/P43DE.pdf)